# Products visibility on homepage

Tags: product, home

Guys I need your help and this is really a serious thing. I’m struggling with the visibility of the products from the day I’ve installed the Electronic Store theme (http://demo.pagayo.com/pagayotheme001/). Every single day I have to scratch my head to think what I’m doing wrong. My products are not being displayed on the homepage regardless of my indefinite attempts to make them appear. I’ve tried every single thing I could do by reading on forums and some blogs, but nothing worked for me. Please, please let me know how can make them visible on homepage? Everything is good according to me:

Status: In Stock

Visible: Enabled

What is missing, then? What is blocking the products from appearing on index page?
One last thing, how can I increase the number of slider? I don’t have sound knowledge of PHP or Magento so it becomes more hard for me to configure the webiste. Additionally I can’t afford the big fat fee of a front-end developer so I hope you guys will help me to solve your problem.
Website: http://www.dirtrades.com

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a third party theme. please contact the developers directly for help.

Comment: Yeah, the first issue may have been a general Magento question, but the the slider issue is most definitely theme related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your stock quantity.  An item has to be In Stock and have quantity greater than 0 to appear.

Comment: I've created 3 configurable products with a stock of 10 quantity each for each variant. Still it's not appearing.

Comment: Configurable products can be a challenge...  You need to make sure that the configurable products are viewable in catalog and search, and that the associated products have quantity stock assigned. Both configurable  and associated products need to be in stock.